# Clearing the "Shell" storage via ADB on Android Emulator

Tags: android, adb

Using an Android Emulator (Nexus5 @ droid 7.1.1) to run my Appium tests against and I've noticed that from time to time the emulator storage becomes full so I have to manually go to *Settings>Storage>Internal Shared Storage>Apps>Show System* and clear the so-called *"Shell"* part (see the screenshot). Any tips on how to clear this via ADB? I really want to automate this part and never do this manually again.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: adb shell pm clear packageName